# How to make a view that is like EditText for SMS code validation?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-custom-view

I want to add multiple inline EditText in my Android application where user can enter text and then the next EditText gets the focus automatically. Like in the image below. I want a sample code (or a library) on how to achieve it.[image]

Answer (score 10):

You can use below libraries:

- [PinEntryEditText](https://github.com/alphamu/PinEntryEditText)
- [VercodeEditText](https://github.com/JustKiddingBaby/VercodeEditText)

or building it using [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/building-a-pinentryedittext-in-android-5f2eddcae5d3)

Comment: VercodeEditText works best! It is more customizable unlike the PinEntryEditText

Answer (score 0):

There's one more library in addition to the ones already mentioned here - [SmsConfirmationView](https://github.com/fraggjkee/sms-confirmation-view)

Answer (score -2):

I also came across this one, and it is quite customizable

[VerificationCodeInputView](https://github.com/Wynsbin/VerificationCodeInputView)

For instance

```
<com.wynsbin.vciv.VerificationCodeInputView
    android:id="@+id/verification_code"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:vciv_et_background="@android:color/white"
    app:vciv_et_foucs_background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
    app:vciv_et_cursor_color="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:vciv_et_height="58dp"
    app:vciv_et_inputType="number"
    app:vciv_et_number="6"
    app:vciv_et_text_color="@android:color/black"
    app:vciv_et_text_size="18sp"
    app:vciv_et_underline_default_color="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    app:vciv_et_underline_focus_color="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    app:vciv_et_underline_height="2dp"
    app:vciv_et_underline_show="true"
    app:vciv_et_width="58dp" />
```

After adding the repo in your root build.gradle file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

You can add the dependency like this

```
implementation 'com.github.Wynsbin:VerificationCodeInputView:1.0.2'
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31216773)